# Is Java ETClient threadsafe?

Tags: fuel-sdk, fuel

Is Java com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient threadsafe?

Comment: What's your use case, exactly? Multiple threads acting as the same user? Different users? Is your code taking too long to run, or are you just trying to eek out a bit more performance?

Comment: I want to know if I can inject ETClient.  Is ETClient threadsafe? Or is this not recommended?

Comment: Can SalesForce team answer the question "Is ETClient threadsafe" definitively?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/exacttarget/fuelsdk/ETClient.java), it appears to have several synchronized functions (in regards to maintaining a session), and the remaining functions look like they don't depend on data in a non-thread-safe manner. As such, it appears that multiple threads can share the same ETClient if you want to.